# Как правильно поставить минимальную дату

Tags: java, android

У меня две кнопки. Первый вылета, второй прилета. У даты вылета minDate = today. А у даты прилета minDate должна быть равной выбранной дате на вылета.

**В onCreate():**

```
final Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    Date today = new Date();
    Date departs;

    initButtonListeners(today, nextYear);
```

**Сами клики:**

```
public void initButtonListeners(final Date today, final Calendar nextYear) {
    findViewById(id.linearCalendar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCalendarInDialog("Выберите дату вылета", R.layout.calendar_dialog_customized);

                dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date(departData));

        }
    });

    findViewById(id.linearArrive).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCalendarInDialog("Выберите дату прилета", R.layout.calendar_dialog_customized);

            Date dates = null;

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
                try {
                    dates = format.parse(departData);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialogView.init(dates, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(new Date(arriveData));
            }

        }
    });

}
```

**OnDateClickListener:**

```
dialogView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
            if(isFrom){
                departData = dateFormat.format(date);
                tvDepart.setText(departData);
            }else{
                arriveData = dateFormat.format(date);
                tvArrive.setText(arriveData);
            }

            theDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

        }

    });
```

**При клике Прилета, вылетает приложение, говорит о нулевом значении**

**Ошибка:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The string argument is null
 at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:373)
 at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:149)
 at com.tezz.MainContent.ContentActivity$2.onClick(ContentActivity.java:305)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Вопрос:**

Что не правильно, как поставить minDate?

Comment: `(new Date(arriveData));` arriveData откуда берете? Выше по коду departData

Comment: Поправил, он был объявлен в самом верху пере onCreate(), а инициализирован в onDateClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потратив немало времени нашел ответ!

```
public static String departData;
public static String arriveData;
Date dep;
Date arr;


    findViewById(id.linearArrive).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCalendarInDialog("Выберите дату прилета", R.layout.calendar_dialog_customized);

            if (dep == null) {
                if (arr != null) {
                    dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                            .withSelectedDate(arr);
                } else {
                    dialogView.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                            .withSelectedDate(new Date());
                }
            } else if (arr == null) {
                dialogView.init(dep, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(dep);
            } else {


                if (dep.after(arr)) {
                    arr = dep;
                    dialogView.init(dep, nextYear.getTime())
                            .withSelectedDate(dep);
                }

                dialogView.init(dep, nextYear.getTime())
                        .withSelectedDate(arr);

            }
        }

    });

    dialogView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        DateFormat dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
            if(isFrom){

                departData = dateFormat.format(date);
                departdOw = dayOfWeek.format(date);
                try {
                    dep = dateFormat.parse(departData);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                tvDepart.setText(departData);

            }else{

                arriveData = dateFormat.format(date);
                arrivedOw = dayOfWeek.format(date);
                try {
                    arr = dateFormat.parse(arriveData);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                tvArrive.setText(arriveData);

            }

            theDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `departData` равен `null`, поэтому приложение падает в строчке `dates = format.parse(departData);`